# generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred; the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time

Tags: swift

The call is something like

```swift
exp(of: 1 + 2 * .i, partiallySummedTo: 10))
```

with definition

```swift
import Foundation
import Numerics

func exp<T>(of z : Complex<T>, partiallySummedTo n : Int) -> Complex<T> {
  Array(0...n).map({
    pow(z, $0) / Array(1...$0).reduce(1, *)
  }).reduce(0, +)
}
```

The part that cannot be typechecked is the `Array(0...n).map({`. For the generic parameter it also wouldn't allow me to do `exp<Int>(of: ...`, explicitly applying the type parameter. The code depends on [swift-numerics](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics).

---

Yes... It's a joke; the file is called `taylor.swift`... (lol) And please tell if in your opinion there is a more elegant way to write this (the series is $\displaystyle e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$).

Comment: Inside the `map` block, split up the code. Assign `pow(z, $0)` to a variable. Assign `Array(1...$0).reduce(1, *)` to a variable. Return the division of the two variables. That fixes your current issue but it brings out a few new ones you need to deal with.

Comment: FYI - Stack overflow does not support math formula formatting.

Comment: are there missing: `import Complex`?

Comment: What type gives pow(z, $0), may be T. T can't be divided by Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do most of the calculations in `Complex` and `T`. Fortunately, you can convert `Int` to these types using [`FloatingPoint.init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/init(_:)-2xwlo).

```
func exp<T>(of z : Complex<T>, partiallySummedTo n : Int) -> Complex<T> {
    // you should use Complex.pow instead of the global function pow
    // Also, clamp $0 to 1, to make sure the range used for the factorial is valid
    (0...n).map({
        Complex.pow(z, Complex<T>($0)) / (1...(max($0, 1))).reduce(Complex.one) { $0 * Complex($1) }
    }).reduce(Complex.zero, +)
}
```

IMO, doing this with a loop is better. You can avoid recalculating the factorial:

```
func exp<T>(of z : Complex<T>, partiallySummedTo n : Int) -> Complex<T> {
    var i = Complex<T>.zero
    var result = Complex<T>.zero
    var factorial = Complex<T>.one
    for _ in 0...n {
        result += Complex.pow(z, i) / factorial
        i += 1
        factorial *= i
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Both works! Thanks a lot! (PS. the `max($0, 1)` requires you to add 1 to the end result, as the power series of exp starts from `i = 0`).

Comment: PPS. I kinda hope that one can do a `pure` annotation etc. so that the factorial can be [memoized](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization). ~~Functional~~ functorial programming rocks!